# How do I get SQL Profiler to show statements with column names like 'password'?

Tags: sql-server, tsql

I'm profiling a database just now and need to see the UPDATE and INSERT statements being executed on a particular table.

However, because the table has a 'Password' column the SQL Profiler is being understandingly cautious and replacing the `TextData` column with:

`-- 'password' was found in the text of this event.`
`-- The text has been replaced with this comment for security reasons.`

How do I prevent it doing this because I need to see the SQL statement being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Revert to sql server 2000 sp3
2. Upgrade to sql server 2005
3. Use this [hack](http://www.andreabertolotto.net/Articles/SP4BlacklistedWordsRemover.aspx) which *PATCHES* sqlservr.exe & definitely not supported by microsoft.

Comment: Oh joy. This is a production box and the bug I'm trying to trace only happens in production. Thanks anyway.

Comment: your only alternative is to rename any reference to password (or other bad words) in the call

Comment: Yeah...Sadly there's no chance of doing that. The column is used all over the sodding place. Talk about security through obscurity. That's one of the worst approaches to solving a [non-]problem I've ever seen. I could go on..... :)

Comment: you're not the only one that thinks this: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/database-development/A-Classic-Security-Challenge-SQL-Profiler-and-Password-Text.aspx

Comment: added your other option... hahaha

Comment: LOL....I wish :)

Comment: We finally migrated off the db's on this box to a new Windows 2008/SQL 2008 R2 environment (its been in the pipeline for a while, this profiler issue bumped things along a bit), so problem solved. I can't believe MS don't have an official hotfix to undo that daft idea.